# What does super mean in Java?

Tags: java

I got a question on a paper, and asks about What does super mean in Java?
With four choices:

- A - `super` means the memory address of current instance
- B - `super` means the memory address of current instance's super instance.
- C - `super` means the super class of current instance.
- D - `super` can be used in `main()` method.

I think the answer should be B, but the answer is C, is the answer's wrong or my wrong?

My translation might not such accurate, you can translate it yourself:

关于super的说法正确的是：
A、是指当前对象的内存地址
B、是指当前对象的父类对象的内存地址
C、是指当前对象的父类
D、可以在main()方法中

Comment: In "standard" Java, there is no way to know the "memory address" of an object.

Comment: The correct answer is C. Explanation: https://www.baeldung.com/java-super

Comment: @assylias But I think the statement of choice C is meaning that the super class is shared.

Comment: You can use `super` inside the main method, but only nested inside an anonymous or local class.

Comment: See the Java Language Specification: [15.11.2. Accessing Superclass Members using `super`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2)

Comment: @Joko I think B can be explained, becuz shouldnt the current instance has an anonymous super instance inside?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> B - super means the memory address of current instance's super instance.

> I think the answer should be B, but the answer is C, is the answer's wrong or my wrong?

You are wrong.  [Marco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67368913/139985) (and the comments) explain why C is correct.

The B answer is incorrect / nonsensical for two reasons:

1. A (normal) Java program cannot access a memory address.  Java uses references, and things are specified in terms of references (not addresses) in Java<sup>1</sup>.
2. There is no such thing as a super instance of an instance.  An instance is both an instance of its (most derived) class, and all of its superclasses **at the same time**.  So the address of the "super instance" would be the same as the address of the instance itself.

---

> I think B can be explained.  Doesn't the current instance have an anonymous super instance inside?

That's not correct.  There is no "inside".  Your explanation is based on an incorrect understanding of object modelling *and* of how Java implements object types / classes.

Think of it this way: does a (real world) cat have anonymous mammal inside?  No.  My pussy cat "Fluffy" *is a* mammal at the same time as she *is a* cat.   When we view a cat as a mammal, we are deliberately ignoring the characteristics that make it cat-like and focus on (just) the characteristic that are mammalian.

Likewise, in Java:

```
public class Mammal {
    ...
}

public class Cat extends Mammal {
    ...
}

Mammal thing = new Cat();
// The 'thing' still refers to a 'Cat', but we can only see the 
// 'Mammal' characteristics

Cat fluffy = (Cat) thing;
// But when we look at it via 'fluffy', we can see it's 'Cat'
// characteristics too.

System.out.println(fluffy == thing);  // prints "true" because they
                                      // refer to the same object.
```

---

<sup>1 - This terminological mistake might be the result of an English -> Chinese or Chinese -> English translation problem.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The answer is C.

`super` is a keyword in Java and it refers to the instance of the super class.

There are different scenarios where you can use it, for example to invoke a method in a super class when you have overriden the same method is the subclass, like this:

```
class MyClass {
   public void myMethod() {
       //Do something
   }
}

public class MySubClass extends MyClass

   public void myMethod() {
      super.myMethod(); // It invokes 'myMethod' parent class's implementation
   }
}
```

An interesting usage is when you want to invoke the constructor of the super class from the constructor of the subclass. In that case, it must be the very first statement of the subclass constructor. However, even if you don't add explicitly that invocation, it will be added by the compiler automatically:

```
public class MySubClass extends MyClass {
   public MySubClass() {
       super(); // If you don't add this statement, it will be added by the compiler
   }
}
```

As already suggested, there is an interesting article from Baeldung, where you can find more examples: https://www.baeldung.com/java-super